# Facebook Graph API unable to get comments from user's post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API seems no way to get any comments other than user itself posted from users' any Post, Album, Photo or Video nowadays. The [/{object-id}/comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v14.0/object/comments) doc said `A User can only query their own comments. Other users' comments are unavailable due to privacy concerns.`, also `For the following nodes, the /comments endpoint returns empty data if you read it with a User access token:`.

[image]

Does it really means Facebook Graph API unable to get user post's full comments in any way?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for "personal use" your own user token then yeah you won't have a choice to bring anything else but if you're using a Page Token for a page that you manage then you can get the posts and comments but I'm currently unable to get the Comments "from" data so I can know who the User is (Name)